# What isn't comparable by the Comparable class?

Tags: java

I know that this class compares two objects in a class(e.g. two Strings), but what types aren't comparable using this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, you can compare everything in Java.

For instance, you have a class `X`, which is incomparable. You can make this class an attribute to another class `C` and make `C` comparable, override its `compareTo()` method.

> For example, it doesn't make sense to compare Colors

This is right. Even though it doesn't make sense, you can. Here is the answer for the question:

> Which color is brighter?

```
public class ComparableColor implements Comparable<ComparableColor> 
{
    Color color;
    public ComparableColor(Color color)
    {
        this.color = color;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(ComparableColor c) 
    {
        return c.color.getAlpha() - this.color.getAlpha();

    }

}
```

Comment: Although this approach does work, it would force you to e.g. wrap every `Color` in a `ComparableColor` and put them in a collection of `ComparableColor` in order to sort them, which is quite cumbersome. The intended way of making it possible to compare instances of a class that does not implement `Comparable` is to create a `Comparator` and supply an instance of it to the collection you need to sort. Then, there is no need for wrapping.

Answer (score 15):

That's not quite how it works. `Comparable` is an *interface* that any class *may* choose to implement in order to indicate that instances of the class may be compared using the class' `compareTo()` method. So you can choose to implement this interface in any class you create yourself (however, you must write the code for `compareTo()` yourself, since Java doesn't know how to compare your objects in a meaningful manner).

Some built-in classes implement `Comparable` and others don't - there might be a list somewhere, but it would be way too long for an SO answer. If you are wondering about whether a specific class implements `compareTo()`, check its documentation (and see if the comparison does what you expect) or simply try to call that method. If there is a built-in or third-party class that does not implement `Comparable`, you need to create a `Comparator` instead in order to compare them.

A `Comparator` may compare anything you wish, because you are the one who decides how it should work.

Answer (score 2):

For example, it doesn't make sense to compare [Colors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html), so this class doesn't implement the Comparable interface. Now, if you want a list of all classes that don't implement Comparable, I don't think there is one out there.

Comment: This actually answers the question. Thanks for the example of what isn't comparable.

Comment: If you prefer, there is any number of possible ways in which you could compare colors, and none of them makes more sense than any other. There is no "natural" order, as in alphabetical for Strings or ascending for Integers.

Comment: @Zoyd Natural ordering has nothing to do with the Comparable interface, and the phrase itself is kind of a misnomer. The natural ordering of a class is the default (e.g., alphabetical for Strings) ordering that Java comes with. It does not necessarily agree with what society as a whole believes to be natural. What you get with the Comparable interface is a *total* ordering, not a natural ordering. Sorting colors by brightness is a perfect example of a total ordering.

Comment: *Comparable implementations provide a natural ordering for a class*, according to the Oracle [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html). The contract of the Comparable interface imposes a total order. Quoting again from the same page : *the natural ordering is a total order on the objects of a class that implements it*.